# Convert Pixel from One Density to Another

Tags: android, pixel, screen-density

Let's assume I have a view standing on 650 of X coordinate and 450 on Y coordinate of Android Screen. The current Android screen has density value of **XHDPI** . How shall I convert this coordinate values so it will stand exactly at the same spot for let's say **MDPI** and **XXHDPI**?

I've tried to get the density of the origin and transfer it to the final place and have calculation like ***->*** ***finalSourceDensity/originalDensity*** and after this calculation I've tried to multiply received x and y coordinates by the result of the divided numbers mentioned above but view still has a lot margin than it needs to.

So for example this is the code I have now.

```
 val densityName = client?.density ?: "mdpi"
        val densityFloat = DeviceUtils.getDeviceDensityValue(densityName)

        val dm = DisplayMetrics()
        windowManager?.defaultDisplay?.getMetrics(dm)

        val screenAdjust = dm.densityDpi / densityFloat


        val finalX = client?.charX ?: 0f * screenAdjust
        val finalY = client?.charY ?: 0f * screenAdjust
```

Any clue?

Comment: pixel? what pixel? what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: the coordinates view currently on  hence, pixels.

I want to move the view and send it via socket to another device so it will be synchronized. The view will be moving to the clicked position on both devices sequentially and correctly

Comment: so you have two different screens (with two different dimensions) and want to show content of the first screen on the other and you dont know how to scale and translate the original?

Comment: well somewhat close to what I want